# Bash returning true false

Tags: bash

Does anyone know why my bash line return 42 in code given below:

true || true && false || return 42

i am wondering why program gets to this point false || return 42

thanks for answering

Comment: possible duplicate of [why is true == false in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579399/why-is-true-false-in-bash)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
true || true && false || return 42
```

They are simply processed in sequence:

First it starts with `true` : Returns 0. `$?` is set to 0.

Then next `|| true` : Not processed since `$?` is 0 from the first `true`.

Then next is `&& false` : Processed since `$?` is still 0 from the first `true`, and now false turns `$?` to 1.

Then last is `|| return 42` : Processed since `$?` is 1 from the last `false`, and code returns 42.